# Show that a Hausdorff space $X$ is regular if and only if $X/A$ is Hausdorff for all $A$ closed in $X$.

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, separation-axioms

> Show that a Hausdorff space $X$ is regular if and only if $X/A$ is Hausdorff for all $A$ closed in $X$.

Assume that $X$ is regular. Let $x, y \in X/A$ such that $x \ne y$. If $x \ne A$ and $y \ne A$, then $q^{-1}(\{x\})=x$ and $q^{-1}(\{y\})=y$. As $X$ is Hausdorff there exists open neighborhoods $U_1$ and $U_2$ of $x$ and $y$ respectively. Now $q$ being surjective implies that $q^{-1}(q(U_1))=U_1$ and $q^{-1}(q(U_2))=U_2$. Since each $U_i$ is open the quotient topology that $X/A$ has implies that $q(U_1)$ and $q(U_2)$ are both open. We also have that $$q^{-1}(q(U_1 \cap U_2))= \emptyset$$ but I don't know if we can derive the result that $q(U_1) \cap q(U_2) = \emptyset$ which would imply that $X/A$ is Hausdorff?

Answer (score 1):

First of all recall the following:

> **Lemma.** If $f:X\to Y$ is a surjective function and $A,B\subseteq Y$ are such that $f^{-1}(A)$ is disjoint from $f^{-1}(B)$ then $A,B$ have to be disjoint as well.

*Proof.* Assume otherwise that $x\in A\cap B$. Then $f^{-1}(x)\subseteq f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(x)\subseteq f^{-1}(B)$. Since $f$ is surjective then $f^{-1}(x)$ is nonempty showing that $f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ are not disjoint. Contradiction. $\Box$

This property reduces the problem "$q(U)$ is disjoint from $q(V)$" to "$q^{-1}(q(U))$ is disjoint from $q^{-1}(q(V))$", which is immediate if $q^{-1}(q(U))=U$ and $q^{-1}(q(V))=V$. However:

> Now $q$ being surjective implies that $q^{-1}(q(U_1))=U_1$

That is unfortunately wrong. The real equality is $q(q^{-1}(F))=F$ for surjective functions. The equality you wrote is for injective functions. In fact consider what happens when $U_1$ intersects $A$ (nothing you wrote stops that from happening). Then $q^{-1}(q(U_1))=U_1\cup A$ which no longer has to be open. And if the same happens for $U_2$ then additionally their images are no longer disjoint, even though they still can be disjoint in $X$ (obviously $A$ has to have more than $1$ element in such scenario).

What you can show is that for a subset $B\subseteq X$ we have

$$q^{-1}(q(B))=\begin{cases}
B&\text{if }B\cap A=\emptyset\\
B\cup A&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

So how do we utilize all of that?

"$\Rightarrow$" Assume $[x],[y]\in X/A$, $[x]\neq[y]$. There are two cases:

1. $[x]\neq A$ and $[y]\neq A$. Then as you wrote $q^{-1}([x])=\{x\}$ and $q^{-1}([y])=\{y\}$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff then so is $X-A$ (which is open) and thus $x$ and $y$ can be be separated by open subsets $U$, $V$ of $X-A$. Therefore $U$, $V$ are open subsets of $X$ that do not intersect $A$. Thus $q^{-1}(q(U))=U$ and $q^{-1}(q(V))=V$ showing that $q(U)$ and $q(V)$ are open and (by our lemma) disjoint in $X/A$.

So my reasoning is almost the same as yours, except I had this one additonal step that my open neighbourhoods are taken in $X-A$ instead of whole $X$. In order to guarantee the $q^{-1}(q(B))=B$ property, which then gives us that images are open and disjoint.

2. One of them is $A$, e.g. $[y]=A$. Then $q^{-1}([x])=\{x\}$ but $q^{-1}([y])=A$. Since $X$ is regular than these can be separated by open neighbourhoods $U$, $V$ of $x$ and $A$ respectively. Note that $U$ doesn't intersect $A$ and thus $q^{-1}(q(U))=U$, while $q^{-1}(q(V))=V\cup A=V$ as well (because $A\subseteq V$). This shows that $q(U)$ and $q(V)$ are open and (by our lemma) disjoint in $X/A$.

"$\Leftarrow$" Let $A\subseteq X$ be a closed subset and $x\in X-A$. Since $X/A$ is Hausdorff then $A$ and $[x]$ can be separated by open subsets $U$, $V$ in $X/A$. It follows that $q^{-1}(U)$ and $q^{-1}(V)$ are open subsets separating $A$ from $x$ in $X$.

Comment: Thanks for a really great answer! Any advice on learning topology? It seems to be a lot about knowing the right definitions, but often in the end you usually need some "enlightment" to finish off the problems.

Comment: So first of all you have to focus on details. This is important in entire math, not only topology. Sometimes there are easy to miss nuances that have huge consequences, like the mistake you've made with preimage of image. But don't worry too much about it, we all make mistakes. Talk with people, ask questions. Do not give up. And I suppose that "learn by doing" is the best advice I can give you.

Answer (score 0):

As $A$ is closed, we may assume that $U_i \cap A = \emptyset$, $i = 1$, $2$ (otherwise replace $U_i$ by $U_i \cap (X \setminus A)$). Then on both $U_i$ $q$ is a bijection, therefore
$$ q[U_1] \cap q[U_2] = q[U_1 \cap U_2] = q[\emptyset] = \emptyset$$
Note that this does not imply $X/A$ being Hausdorff, you still have to consider the case $x = A$, $y \ne A$. Use regularity here.