If $X$ is regular and $A$ is a closed subset of $A$, then $X/A$ is Hausdorff

If $X$ is regular and $A$ is a closed subset of $A$, then $X/A$ is Hausdorff

How can I use to canonical quotient map $q: X \to X/A$ to prove the result? I tried picking distinct elements $x, y \in X/A$ and treating them differently considering if they are in $A$ or not, but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Hint: Regularity in particular says that for every point $x \in X \setminus A$ there exist open neighborhoods $U \ni x$ and $V \supset A$ with $U \cap V = \emptyset$. How can you use these to separate the points  $q(x)$ and $q(A)$ in the quotient?

That was my question, I can't seem to be able to figure out that part.

Okay, further hint: Consider $q(U)$ and $q(V)$; by definition these satisfy $q(x) \in q(U)$, $q(A) \in q(V)$, and $q(U) \cap q(V) = \emptyset$, so if you can manage to show that $q(U)$ and $q(V)$ are open (if in doubt, look up the definition of the quotient topology), then you've successfully separated the $q(x)$ and $q(A)$ by open sets. Show this first and then think about how to separate $q(x)$ and $q(y)$ for $x \neq y \notin A$. :)

Seee also the 3 other duplicates linked to the latter.

Let $X$ be a regular space and $A \subseteq X$ closed. The quotient space $X / A$ consists of $A$ along with singletons $\{ x \}$, where $x \notin A$; the map $q: X \to X / A$ can be defined as
$$q (x) = \begin{cases}
A & x \in A \\
\{ x \} & x \notin A
\end{cases}$$
Now, just as you suggested, we can take three cases. Let $B \ne C \in X / A$.
In the first case, $B \ne A$ and $C \ne A$. That means that $B = \{ b \}$ and $C = \{ c \}$, where $b \ne c \in X$ and $b, c \notin A$. Since $X$ is regular, it is Hausdorff, so there exist disjoint neighborhoods $U$ of $b$ and $V$ of $c$. Further, since $A$ is closed (and misses $b, c$), the neighborhoods $U' = U \cap (X - A), V' = V \cap (X - A)$ separate $b, c$. Since $U', V'$ are saturated, their images $q (U'), q (V')$ are open and separate $B, C$.
In the other two cases, exactly one of $B, C$ is equal to $A$. WLOG, suppose $B = A$, and $C \ne A \implies C = \{ c \}$, where $c \notin A$. Since $X$ is regular, there exists an open set $U$ containing $A$ that is disjoint from a neighborhood $V$ of $c$. It is easy to see that $U, V$ are saturated, so their images $q (U), q (V)$ are open and separate $A, C$.

The question was a multiduplicate, hence so is your answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487318, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528621, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4367709
